# C forking: child proc-meant printf messages appear only after the whole program finishes

Tags: c, fork

Got this code:

```
static void
prime_test(void)
{
    fprintf(stdout, "child prime_test process started\n");
    int num;
    fprintf(stdout, "enter your num: ");
    fscanf(stdin, "%d", &num);
    fprintf(stdout, "you entered %d\n", num);
    if (num == -1) {
        fprintf(stdout, "-1 is the wrong value\nnow exiting prime_test...\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int i;
    int  count = 0;
    fprintf(stdout, "processing numbers...\n");
    for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
            count++;
            fprintf(stdout, "%d divides %d\n", i, num);
        }
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "---------------------\n");
    fprintf(stdout, "%d has %d divisors\n\n", num, count);
    sleep(1);
}

int
main(void)
{
    system("clear");
    fprintf(stdout, "main() started\n");
    while (1) {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        switch (pid) {
            case -1:
                fprintf(stderr, "failed to fork\n");
                exit(1);
            case 0:
                fprintf(stdout, "now in child\n");
                prime_test();
                break;
            case 1:
                fprintf(stdout, "now in parent\n");
                break;
        }
        if (pid != 0) {
            int child_status;
            pid_t child_pid = wait(&child_status);
            fprintf(stdout, "child process with pid=%d finished\n", child_pid);
            if (WIFEXITED(child_status)) {
                fprintf(stdout, "child process with pid=%d exited with code %d\n", child_pid, child_status);
                break;
            }
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I print divisors until user enters (-1). If -1 I exit. It works OK! My problem is I wanna have the messages within `if (pid != 0)` appearing right after I quit `prime_test()`. But they appear only after I exit the whole program by entering -1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you *want* isn't necessary what can happen. In the block `if( pid != 0)`, you've used a `wait()`. Which means you're going to block the parent thread until the child completes execution. Also the statements print that the child completed execution and also print the exit code. Logically you can only print the exit code after the thread completes.

Now if you want to print something from the parent to get a sense that the parent is executing concurrently, I'd suggest adding `fprintf(stdout,"Parent process waiting for child to complete...");` before the `wait()` function.

Comment: Sorry, did I say 'coded'?  I meant to say 'copied';)

Comment: As Pooja Nilangekar suggested I moved my printfs before wait() and got I what I wanted! Thanx, Pooja Nilangekar!!  "What you want isn't necessary what can happen" - that's the best educational tip I got this year